# Android Beacon Library didExitRegion not called

Tags: android, beacon

I'm very new to beacons and i'm trying to implement basic detection of an Estimote beacon (virtual via the Estimote iOS App) with the AltBeacon Android Beacon Library.

When I activate the beacon my app detects it and comes into the "didEnterRegion" callback. But when I power off the beacon / or go away "didExitRegion" is never called.

I use the sample code of http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have asked to fast. After a while (depending on the scan interval) didExitRegion will be called.